# Inline CSS Responsive Embedded Video with Max Width

Tags: html, video, responsive-design, embed, inline

My question is about how I can use inline CSS to embed a YouTube video so that it will not only be responsive, but have a maximum size, and stay centered on the page. (I know I shouldn't be using inline CSS! I'm only using it because I can't work on anything but the HTML file.) When I first embedded it, it had a fixed size, so it didn't fit mobile screens. I found resources online that showed me how to make it responsive to fit the width of the page, so I pretty much copy and pasted it into the HTML as they directed. It reads as follows:

```
<div style="position:relative;
padding-bottom:56.25%;
padding-top:35px;
height:0;
overflow:hidden;">
   <iframe style="position:absolute;
    top:0;
    left:0;
    width:100%;
    height:100%;
    "width="560"
    height="315"
    src="redacted for privacy"
    frameborder="0"
    allow="autoplay; encrypted-media"
    allowfullscreen="">
    </iframe>
</div>
```

Now, it's perfectly responsive, but it looks huge on desktop because it's full-width. I'd like to edit the code so that it maxes out at a certain size; say about 600px wide for instance. I have some basic HTML/CSS knowledge but I'm totally unclear as to what's doing what in this code snippet. The code looks kind of weird to me, and none of the tweaks I've tried has been able to get it to max out at a certain size and/or stay centered on the page.

Comment: Ok, so now the code looks like this, how do I center it?
`<div style="position: relative;
padding-bottom: 56.25%;
padding-top: 35px;
height: 0;
overflow: hidden;">
    <iframe style="position: absolute;
        top:0;
        left: 0;
        width: 100%;
        max-width:600px;
        max-height:400px;
        height: 100%;
        height= "315"
        src= "redacted for privacy"
        frameborder="0"
        allow="autoplay; encrypted-media"
        allowfullscreen=>
        </iframe>
</div>`

Answer (score 2):

I have edited your code please use this and your video will be perfectly centered in respect to every screen resolution.

```
<div style="position: relative; padding-bottom: 56.25%; padding-top: 35px; height: 0; overflow: hidden;"> <iframe style="position: absolute; top:0; left: 50%; transform:translateX(-50%);-webkit-transform:translateX(-50%);-moz-transform:translateX(-50%); width: 100%; max-width:600px; max-height:400px; height: 100%;" src= "redacted for privacy" frameborder="0" allow="autoplay; encrypted-media" allowfullscreen=> </iframe> </div>
```

Comment: Thank you so much! I have one more problem: once the video hits its maximum size, there starts being a large space between the video and the rest of the content on the page, because the div it is in keeps getting larger. Do you know how I fix that?

Comment: Can you have any link where i can see that.

Comment: Remove the padding-bottom: 56.25%; style from the div, i think it will help.

Comment: That worked, but it also made the video into a narrow horizontal strip.

Comment: Add a height to the div.

Answer (score 0):

leave your width set to 100% then add another attribute of: `max-width:600px;`

Comment: also, you have extra quoatation marks in your code, the set starting before width:560 should be deleted and at the end of the css you have two closing sets. take one of those out. Also do not set "width" in the css twice. delete the 560px, right now you have width set to 100% and 560px.

Comment: Thanks, just tried it! It cropped the sides of the video and moved it to the left side. It helped when I added a corresponding max-height, but it's still left justified. Do you know how I fix that?

Comment: when you have `position:absolute` the numbers after right and left are how far from the right and left edge it will sit, so you could set `left:10;right:10;` to give it a little room on the sides. But as long as those two numbers are equal it will be horizontally centered. Set top and bottom to the same numbers the center it vertically.

Comment: Thanks! If I add `left:[value]; right:[value];` it nudges the video over to the right, but it's still not centered. And at smaller sizes, it gets square shaped and cuts off the right side. Anything else I could try?